# Cannot bind argument to parameter because it is an empty string

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I am getting this error when calling a function from a module that I have created and imported into my main script:

```
 Run-RemoteScript : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Targets' because it 
is an empty string.
At C:\Scripts\Script.ps1:114 char:39
+             Run-RemoteScript -Targets $targets -RunMethod $runMethod  ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Run-RemoteScript], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Run-RemoteScript`
```

In my module, `-Target` is defined as a parameter like this:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)][String[]]$Targets,
```

In my main script (which imports my module), `$targets` is defined like this:

```
$Targets = Set-TargetList
```

I have tried using a `global` script scope, but this did not work.

Comment: So.. what does function `Set-TargetList` return. Is that a `[string[]]` array?

Comment: @Theo Yes, `Set-TargetList` returns a `[string[]]` array.

Comment: @TobiasKKS: Can you dump the type of `$Targets` in your script? You can use `$Targets.GetType()`. The error says that `$targets` is an empty string, not a string array. Thx

Comment: @Moerwald I did a `$Targets.GetType()` whereever `$Targets` is referenced, and they all returned `String[]` and `System.Array`

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? Type `$PSVersionTable`. You can also try to wrap `$targets` in another array -> `Run-RemoteScript -Targets (,$targets) .. `.

Comment: Simple answer: `[string]` can be `$null`.  You need to validate each entry in your array before using it: `if ($null -ne $item) { ... }`

Comment: I'm on v5. Wrapping `$targets` seems to work, but I'm getting an error saying `Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid.`

Answer (score 21):

In my case, it was an array of strings. It was rejected when at least one of the member strings was empty or null.

Either set `AllowEmptyString` as an attribute in the parameter you're calling, or check whether the members are not empty strings before passing them.

Answer (score 1):

Got this error when using a `AzureResourceGroup` project in Visual Studio 2022 after downloading a template from Azure Portal.

[image]

Even though I was using a parameter file from Azure with every parameter needed Visual Studio opened this Powershell window:

[image]

When not typing a name I got the error below in Visual Studio Output:

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'nameFromTemplate' because it is an empty string.

Turns out Visual Studio `AzureResourceGroup` project can not handle a parameter named "name" even though Microsofts own template generator generates this. After renaming the parameter to `appName` everything worked.